# .htaccess same url with or without /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am doing a painful rewrite of many urls on a website I am currently working on, but I have noticed a small problem:

```
RewriteRule ^domains/transfer$ ./cart.php?gid=11 [L,NC]
```

This line with navigate if I go to:

```
http://my-site/domains/transfer
```

But it won't work with a trailing /:

```
http://my-site/domains/transfer/
```

Is there a way I can change the RewriteCode to take either argument and go to the same page. It seems wasteful to have the same line twice to include a '/'

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^domains/transfer/?$ ./cart.php?gid=11 [L,NC]
```

The magic is here: `/?` and that allows for the preceding character, in this case the slash (`/`), to be optional.

If you want something to come after the `transfer`, then remove the dollar sign (`$`) which marks the end of the allowable matching.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to allow just one URL form, the one with or without the trailing slash, and redirect if malformed:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a reason for allowing one but not the other? Is it a program issue, or more of just a correctness one?

Comment: @frodosghost: It is a correctness issue. Every resource should have only one valid URL.

Comment: @Gumbo :: Thanks. Shall implement.